# Computability of esolangs

Tags: discussion

Are there any esoteric programming languages whose computability have not yet been well-classified?  For instance, languages which are not yet known to be Turing-complete.

Comment: I wrote an esoteric language named ["brain-flak"](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak) that is supposed to be turing complete, but I haven't proven it yet. It's also not proven (and probably never will be) if [bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum) is turing complete or not.

Comment: [I have](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Fuck-to-Flak)

Comment: I wrote a complete compiler from P'' (Brainfuck - I/O) into brain-flak. Since P'' is Truing complete so must be brain-flak.

Comment: http://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Unknown_computational_class

Comment: I don't think this is on topic for meta though. It seems like a question that would better be asked in chat once you have 20 reputation (anywhere on the network). You could either try our main chatroom http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte or our esolangs chatroom http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27364/esoteric-programming-languages.